# Cannot figure out how to change selected cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have the following script:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const resultA1Notation = "D2"; // Change
  const range = e.range;
  const selectedValue = range.getValue();
  if (selectedValue === "UPGRADE") {
    let numberValue = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    if (numberValue !== "Free") {
      numberValue = numberValue.slice(0, -1); // Remove P
      const resultCell = sheet.getRange(resultA1Notation);
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() - numberValue);
      sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't get it to work through. I'm trying to modify these two lines:

```
sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
```

I'm trying to get the script to offset the cell by -1, ex if it's B1 it would go to A1. Any help it appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue()` is not using the appropriate syntax as the Class Sheet hasn't a range property. Use `range.offset(0, -1).getValue()`

Note 1:

Using "getActive" methods like `getActiveSheet()`, `getActiveRange()`, etc. under some circunstances might not work as expected. It's better to use the event object properties, i.e. instead of

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

use

```
const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
```

Note 2:

The line

```
resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
```

will overwrite the value set by a previous line

```
resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() - numberValue);
```